# SocialFramework like textfield

Tags: ios, textfield

I would like to  create a multiline textfield, like the one the Apple's SocialFramework uses:

[image]

Is there any default class to achieve this (including the line separators) ?

If not, how could i manage to do it?

Thanks in advance.